# Hacer un contador con condicional en Datatables

Tags: javascript, datatables, condiciones, count

Hola tengo una duda de como poder realizar un contador ya que estoy usando datatables, actualmente tengo datos que me muestran la orden de compra en una columna y si no posee una pues hago una condicional con laravel plantilla blade para que me muestra un guion "-" o signo de resta ,ahora quiero poder hacer que solo me cuente los datos que tengan una orden
ya realice un contador que me realiza la función de que me cuente cuantos datos tengo

```
var contador =  table.rows().count();
$("#counta").text((+contador));
```

dejo una imagen de mi tabla de la sección de ordenes de compra

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podría adaptar esa función para que no realice el conteo si posee un guion o el signo de resta "-" que se muestra cuando no posee una orden

Este es mi código de Datatables

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var table = $('#servicios').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    ordering: true,
    "pageLength": 50,
    "lengthMenu": [[5,10,50,-1], [5,10,50,"All"]],
    "order": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
    "autoWidth": false,
    "language":{
      "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.21/i18n/Spanish.json"
    }
  });
 

  var contador =  table.rows().count();
  $("#counta").text((+contador));

  //Contador de  la columna de ordenes de compra  

  var contador_oc =  table.column(24).rows().count();
  $("#counta_oc").text((+contador));
  });
```

Agradecería mucho si me ayudan a resolverlo

Answer (score 0):

Este seria la solución que le di a mi duda de como hacer un contador evitando los que poseen un guion en una columna

```
var contador_oc = table.column(24).data()
.reduce( function ( a, b ){
return b !== '-' ? a + 1 : a;
}, 0 );
$("#counta_oc").text((+contador));
```

Comment: No olvides explicar brevemente (en la respuesta, no como comentario) lo que hace el código. Tampoco olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.